# C++ string function return statement

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to add int to string in a return statement like so:

```
string Birthday::asString() {
    return this -> day + "/" + this -> month + "/" + this -> year;
}
```

and getting the following error:

> Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

I'm kind of new to C++.

Comment: [sscce.org](http://sscce.org). Or, in other words: Neither "string" nor "Birthday" nor "this" nor "day" nor "month" nor "year" are actually defined in the code snippet you have posted.

Comment: What are the types of `day`, `month` and `year`?

Comment: Also, this is the first time I saw anyone putting spaces between operands of `->`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easiest way to do what you are trying to do is to use ostringstream(found in header `<sstream>`):

```
string Birthday::asString() {
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << this -> day << "/" << this -> month << "/" << this -> year;
    return out.str();
}
```

You are getting the error you show because `C++` does not know how to add an integer to a string.

EDIT: as suggest in M M.'s answer since C++11 there is another option, namely to use the function std::to_string.

Comment: Is there a way for doing this without creating an object ? I think that is a better practice

Comment: @user1970719 you need to convert the integers to strings so you will need to create a new object.

Comment: @user1970719: The object being the ostringstream instance?  Actually the ostringstream solution is superior in terms of performance than the `std::to_string` solution.

Comment: @user1970719: There is very little you can do without creating an object. But you can turn this into [a general-purpose reusable macro](http://www.rootdirectory.de/wiki/SSTR%28%29).

Comment: No, the easiest way is to use `std::to_string`. Yes it is C++11, but this is the current standard (and thus the default) so you should probably mention that your solution is for the older C++03.

Comment: @syam though I agree I must mention this alternative(and I already did in an edit) I still think what I suggest is a bit easier to both read and write in this case.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: I understand your point of view even though I don't agree with your reasons: **I** tend to find code easier to read (and write too) when I can "parse it in my mind" in smaller tokens, and IMHO to_string is a winner here. But hey, both solutions are perfectly valid, and if one uses C++11 it's only a matter of personal choice and style. :) Also, I *may* (ahem) have a *slight* (re-ahem) bias against ostringstream but that's just me. ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
string Birthday::asString() {
     return std::to_string(this->day) + "/" +
            std::to_string(this->month) + "/" +
            std::to_string(this->year);
}
```

*Available since C++11*

Comment: It is also available in not yet c++11 [MSVC10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee404875%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) It lacks some C++11 overloads thru and may require some casts.